# LocalStorage getdata from object

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So I am trying to retrieve date from "Key: value" where data stored in values in nested format and I am getting confused with it following is the data format.

```
key = one0

value = bash: [{question: {id: 0, type: "box", qid: "b"}}, {answer: {dropEffect: "move", id: "1", aid: "d"}}]


0: {question: {id: 0, type: "box", qid: "b"}}

question: {id: 0, type: "box", qid: "b"}
id: 0
qid: "b"
type: "box"

1: {answer: {dropEffect: "move", id: "1", aid: "d"}}

answer: {dropEffect: "move", id: "1", aid: "d"}
aid: "d"
dropEffect: "move"
id: "1"
```

I want to get key and value = `question.id` or `answer.id` from where I can match the solution.

Comment: Can you explain your problem a little bit more?

Comment: thanks, Jose, but I already figured it out, I wanted to access the answerID from values

Answer (score 1):

I manipulated the data to an `object` using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const data = [{question: {id: 0, type: "box", qid: "b"}}, {answer: {dropEffect: "move", id: "1", aid: "d"}}];

const res = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const propName = Object.keys(item)[0];
    acc[propName] = item[propName];

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log('Question id: ', res.question.id); // 0
console.log('Answer id: ', res.answer.id); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself.

```
 let user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(one0))
 let answer = user && user.Storage[1].answer.id 
 console.log(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first function record the information.
The second extracts information from LocalStorage

```
// SAVE
function save_to_LocalStorage () {
    var myValue = ({question: {id: 0, type: "box", qid: "b"}, answer: {dropEffect: "move", id: "1", aid: "d"}});
    localStorage.setItem("someName", JSON.stringify(myValue));
}

// LOAD
function load_from_LocalStorage () {
    var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("someName");
    var myValue = JSON.parse(retrievedData);

    console.log(myValue.question.id);  // question id
    console.log(myValue.answer.id);   // answer id
}
```